# Tryiing to sanitize user input with regex vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to compare the input (username and password) stored from a login_form.asp that calls my login.asp validation page.  I have the code working except for the regex condition.  The page crashes when I add the if statement to compare condition before moving on.  I only want a-z0-9 input allowed before connection attempt.  if I comment out the if conditions, the form validation works, but not the regex.  This is ASP Classic.  Thanks for any insight or help.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
dim userName, password, query
dim conn, rs
Dim reg
Set reg = new RegExp
reg.Pattern = "[a-z0-9] + @[a-z0-9\.] +"

userName = Request.Form("userName")
password = Request.Form("password")

response.write userName & "<P>"

if reg.Test("userName") then
response.write "regex userName = true"
endif

if reg.Test("password") then
response.write "regex password = true"
endif

set conn = server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")

query = "select UserName from users where userName='" & userName & "'   
and     userPass='" & password & "'"
response.write query & "<P>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

regext.test(username)

instead of

regex.test("username")

the 2nd one runs the string literal "username", instead of the variable, into regex.test()

your regex pattern looks odd too.

regexlib.com has a searchable selection of regexes..

and finally, you might rethink your approach to doing the database queries. how you are doing it is open to sql injection attack. use the Parameters object for ado.